# How to clear my counter-strike source settings?

Tags: source-engine, counter-strike-source

if i delete the config file steam just downloads it again.

*This is some filler text to beat the spam filter.*

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

1. Navigate to the store page for the game you wish to reset and get the appID from the URL
   It should look like this: http://store.steampowered.com/app/appID/
2. Disable Steam Cloud
3. Navigate to `"Steam\SteamApps\<username>\<game>\<game>\cfg \"` and delete “config.cfg”
4. Navigate to `"Steam\userdata\<usernumber>\<appID>\remote\c fg\"` and delete “config.cfg”
5. Launch the game, allow it to write a new config file, then exit the game
6. Enable Steam Cloud
7. Launch the game and test the issue.

Comment: To save the asker the hassle of looking around, the appID of CS:S is [240](http://store.steampowered.com/app/240/)